# Is there a way to insert empty row/column to matrix in R?

Tags: r

It could sound like silly question, but I want to add "literally" empty row(Which is not "" or NA) to a matrix. So that I can visually separate rows by inserting a blank row but not harming the look of the matrix. Is this possible..?

Comment: When you say "visually separate", where are you viewing the matrix? Are you printing it to the console, or exporting it to a file of some kind?

Comment: As Calum hints, the best way to do this is probably within a print method, not the matrix itself. A matrix must have all elements of the same type, so if you have a numeric matrix, your only option of things to put in it are numbers (or `NA_numeric_`). You could do something like add an *attribute* given row numbers after which you want a break, and then write a custom print method to print a blank line after those row numbers.